Text adjustment after cell height change
I am trying to recreate a table in R that was originally created in Word. The purpose is to have Rmarkdown create word documents with this table template. I have adjusted cell width and height as the original but after changing the height the text in the cells did not follow the changes. I have tried using valign to center the vertical alignment of the text but it does nothing. How can I place the text vertically aligned in the table's cells?
What I want it to look:

How it's looking:

This is the code I am using:
column_names <- c("Date", "DD(Month)2024")
row_names <- c("identifier", "diameter", "depth", "type", "duration (hh:mm:ss)")
pil_table <- data.frame(Date = row_names, DD.Month.2024 = rep(NA, length(row_names))) 

set_flextable_defaults(font.family = "Arial Nova Cond", font.size = 9, theme_fun = theme_box)

pil_table <- flextable(pil_table)
pil_table <- pil_table %>%
    width(j = 1,
          width = 3.8) %>%
    width(j = 2,
          width = 1.36) %>%
    align(align = "center", part = "header") %>%
    valign(valign = "center", part = "all") %>%
    height_all(height = 0.2) %>%
    hrule(rule = "exact", part = "all") %>%
    bg(i = 1, j = 1:2, bg = "#034F94", part = "header") %>%
    color(pil_table, i = 1, j = 1:2, color = "white", part = "header")`

These are all the libraries being used in the markdown:
library("officedown")
library("officer")
library("bookdown")
library("here")
library("xlsx")
library("DescTools")
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")
library("grid")
library("colf")
library("dplyr")
library("lubridate")
library("gridExtra")
library("bookdown")
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
library("ftExtra")
library("tidyverse")
library("png")
library("gridExtra")
library("flextable")


could you share pil_table?

Just added the lines for the data frame construction above.

The issue you have is that padding makes the cells higher than .2.
You can reduce that padding, below I set it to 1 for all tables.
library(flextable)

column_names <- c("Date", "DD(Month)2024")
row_names <- c("identifier", "diameter", "depth", "type", "duration (hh:mm:ss)")
pil_table <- data.frame(Date = row_names, DD.Month.2024 = rep(NA, length(row_names))) 

set_flextable_defaults(font.family = "Arial", font.size = 9, theme_fun = theme_box,
                       padding = 1)

pil_table <- flextable(pil_table)
pil_table <- pil_table |>
  width(j = 1,
        width = 3.8) |>
  width(j = 2,
        width = 1.36) |>
  align(align = "center", part = "header") |>
  valign(valign = "center", part = "all") |>
  height_all(height = 0.2) |>
  hrule(rule = "exact", part = "all") |>
  bg(i = 1, j = 1:2, bg = "#034F94", part = "header") |>
  color(pil_table, i = 1, j = 1:2, color = "white", part = "header")
pil_table |> print(preview = "docx")




Ah!!! Beautiful! It worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I did not consider padding, nor did I know how it affected the table. Just learned something new for the more complex tables to come.
